# Disrupt Sleep() on Windows in C

Tags: c, multithreading, sleep

I am writing a Gif animator in C.

I have two threads running in parallel, both . The first allows the user to alter the speed of the animation. The second draws the current frame, and then calls `Sleep(Constant * 100 / CurrentSpeed)`, where `CurrentSpeed` is a percentage amount, ranging from *1* to *200*.

The problem is that if you quickly change the speed from *100%*, to *1%*, and then back to the first, the second thread will execute the following:

`Sleep(Constant * 100)`

This will draw frame A, wait many seconds (although the speed was changed by the user), and only then draw B and the following frames in the default speed.

It seems to me that `Sleep` is a poor choice of mine in this case. What can I do to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

The code I currently have (Simplified):

```
while (1) {
    InvalidateRect(Handle, &ImageRect, FALSE);

    if (shouldDispose) {
            break;
    }

    if (DelayTime)
        Sleep(DelayTime * 100 / CurrentSpeed);

    SelectNextImage();
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a timer. When the user changes the speed, stop the running timer, calculate the amount of time that would be left with relative scaling, and schedule a new timer. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling `Sleep()` with the desired frame rate, why don't you call it with a constant interval of 1 ms, for example, and use a variable as a counter?

For example, let `C` be a global variable (counter) which is loaded with a number of 'ticks' of 1ms. Then, write the loop:

```
while(1) { //Main loop of the player thread 
    if (C > 0) C--;
    if (C == 0) nextframe(); //if counter reaches 0, load next frame.
    Sleep(1);
}
```

The control thread would load `C` with a number of 1ms ticks (i.e. frame rate), and the player thread will never be stopped beyond 1 ms. The use of 1ms as the base rate is arbitrary. Use the minimum time that allows you the maximum frame rate, in order to load CPU the less as possible.

**EDIT**

After some hot comments (arguing is good after all), I'd like to point out that this solution is sub-optimal, i.e., it doesn't use any OS mechanism for signaling threads or any other API for preventing the thread from wasting CPU time. The solution shown here is generic: it may be used in any system (even in embedded systems without any running OS. But above all, it is based on the original code posted by the user that asked the question: using `Sleep()`, how can I achieve my purpose. I give him my humble answer. Anyway, I encourage other people to write sample code using the appropriate API for achieving the same goal. With no hard feelings, special thanks to Martin James.

Comment: Depending on what else is running on the PC, the version of the OS and the hardware platform, Sleep is likely to have a much coarser resolution than one ms (15ms is common, 10ms has been in the past).

Comment: This is inefficient. It drains the battery like crazy because the CPU can never sleep for long.

Comment: I can't believe that this sleep(1) loop has been accepted as an answer:(

Comment: The documentation of sleep makes it clear that sleep(1) can sleep for more than 1ms.

Comment: This is a rather troublesome solution. Prior to Win8 (which is mostly tickless), `Sleep(1)` will round to the next scheduler tick (15.6ms), so you effectively sleep 7.3ms on the average -- unless you change the timer granularity to 1ms, which is a system-wide setting that seriously affects power consumption.

Comment: Obviously this is a coarse and not exact solution, but we are not talking about a Real Time application in  RTOS. We're just animating a GIF. The 1ms election is arbitrary.  We don't need 30fps so a larger interval value can be used, for example, 100ms.

Comment: If this solution has been accepted is because it works and it's enough for the user needs.

Comment: Well, if I want to go to a meeting in Germany, I could just start off a week early and walk to the ferry port, cross to Zeebruge and walk on from there.  It works, and meets the requirement.  OTOH, I could buy an airline ticket and so not piss away my limited resources of time and energy in a manner that can be easily avoided.

Comment: That's a quite unfair comparison. Again, this is not a real time app, and it would also work in a 180Mhz machine with 32MB of RAM. I agree you there are better ways to achieve that purpose, but look at the bright side of this code: it's simple and portable (with a wrapper function for sleep). Java and Python make programming easier, but programs are less efficient than those written in C. Why do we program in these languages? Because we assume to sacrifice a little bit of efficiency in the benefit of simplicity. Anyway, I bet your solution will be hundreds of times better than this.

Comment: 'Gif animator' is not exactly transactional, it requires rendering guarantees.  My 'solution' would also be hugely more efficient and latencey-free on a 180Mhz machine with 32MB of RAM - only the scale changes, (yes, I do embedded as well).  'hundreds of times better than this' kinda depends on the interval.  With short intervals, it may only be hundreds, rather than billions.  There is not much 'bright side' when ignoring/avoiding all available inter-thread comms mechanisms available.

Answer (score 1):

Find a synchro API on your OS that allows a wait with a timeout, eg. WaitForSingleObject() on Windows.  If you want to change the delay, change the timeout and signal the event upon which the WFSO is waiting to make it return 'early' and restart the wait with the new timeout.

Polling with Sleep(1) loops is rarely justifiable.

Answer (score 0):

Create a waitable timer. When you [set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the timer, you can specify a callback function that will run in the setting thread's context. This means you can do it with two threads, but it actually works just fine with only a single thread as well.

The main advantage of a waitable timer is, however, that it is more accurate and more reliable than `Sleep`. A timer is conceptually much different from `Sleep` insofar as `Sleep` only gives up control and the scheduler marks the thread as ready to run when the time is up and when the scheduler runs anyway. It doesn't do anything beyond that. Which means that the thread will eventually be scheduled to run again, like any other thread that is ready.
A thread that is waiting on a timer (or other waitable object) causes the scheduler to run when the timer is up and has its priority temporarily boosted. It therefore runs not only more reliably and more closely to the desired time, but also earlier than all other threads with the same base priority. Which does not give a realtime guarantee but at least gives a sort of "soft guarantee".

If you still want to use `Sleep`, use `SleepEx` instead which you can alert, either by [queueing an APC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684954%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or by calling the undocumented [`NtAlertThread`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/APC/NtAlertThread.html) function.
In any case, `Sleep` is troublesome not only because of being unreliable, but also because it bases on the granularity of the system-wide timer. Which you can, of course, set to as low as 1ms (or less on some systems), but that will cause a lot of unnecessary interrupts.